# How to improve performance of CNN denoising autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

[**I am using a convolutional auto encoder for denoising ECG system using the following model.But my model output is good enough.** ]
[figure ECG signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy2TS.png)

```
from keras import layers

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(feature, depth))

x = Conv1D(256, 16, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(input_img)
x = Conv1D(128, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2 )(x)
#x = layers.Conv1D(32, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2 )(x)
encoded =Conv1D(32, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2 )(x)



x = Conv1DTranspose(32, 16,activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2 )(encoded)
x = Conv1DTranspose(64, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2 )(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn3')(x)
x = Conv1DTranspose(128, 16, activation='relu', padding='same',strides=2)(x)
x = Conv1DTranspose(256, kernel_size=16, activation='relu', padding='same')(x) 


decoded = Conv1DTranspose(1, 16, activation='sigmoid', padding='same',strides=2)(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)

autoencoder.summary()
```

What  should  i change?As my ECG signal is normalized to -1 to 1, so what will be the appropriate activation function

Comment: Leaky Relu will perform better

Comment: As Sadia said: Try leaky relu, it seems to perform better with deconvolutions. You should aslo try to use skip connections